# Boot a bootcamp Windows 7 install from Snow Leopard?

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, virtualbox, virtualization, boot-camp

Is there a way to boot a Windows 7 install on BootCamp from a Mac OS X Snow Leopard install.  I hear that you can boot from Parrallels and VMware fusion.b

Answer (score 0):

VMWare Fusion and Parallels Desktop allow you to boot an existing Boot Camp partition. VMWare Fusion has an assistant to help you do that. Parallels to (i think).